# How to validate "input type file" using jQuery validation engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery validation engine to validate a form in my Laravel's project, it works perfect for all of the fields except input type file.

Here is what I have tried:

## Form

```
<form id="series-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="series_fname" id="series_fname" class="validate[required]">
    <input type="text" name="series_lname" id="series_lname" class="validate[required]">
    <input type="file" name="series_image" id="series_image" class="validate[required]" value="Upload Image"/>
</form>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#series-form").validationEngine({promptPosition : "topLeft", 'custom_error_messages': {
       '#series_fname': {
            'required': {
                'message': "* This field is required"
            }
        },
       '#series_lname': {
            'required': {
                'message': "* This field is required"
            }
        },
        '#series_image': {
            'required': {
                'message': "* This field is required"
            }
        },
    });
});
```

The first two are working fine, but it's not working for image.

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin has absolutely nothing to do wth the jQuery Validation Engine.  Edited tags.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you already set a value for that field making the validation engine believe it has a value already, even though it's not a file. You should remove the `value="Upload Image"`

```
<input type="file" name="series_image" id="series_image" class="validate[required]"/>
```